# O fluxo de uso das tags de Stream está correto?

Tags: debate, suporte, tags, tag-específica

Vamos ver:

[stream](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream) é usada para fluxo de dados em geral. Todas perguntas lá estão com ela adequadamente? precisaria de alguma mais específica? ´Há algum abuso? Alguém se habilita criar uma boa definição e indicação de uso na Wiki da tag?

[stream-de-arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-de-arquivos) é uma mais específica. Pelo que eu vi está tudo certo no seu uso. Concordam? Uma descrição com indicação de uso cairia bem...

[inputstream](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inputstream) é para um tipo específico (do Java). Ela é necessária? Está tudo ok lá?

[streaming](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streaming) é outro assunto. É para transmissão de mídia. Está tudo ok nas perguntas desta *tag*?

[sslstream](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sslstream) é outro assunto e parece tudo ok, só coloquei para confirmarem.

Já dei um jeito em outras que não eram importantes. Vamos dar a devida importância para cada *tag*, vamos pensar no que colabora na organização ou que é mais ruído e não vai acrescentar nada. Lembremos do nosso tamanho e do potencial que podemos chegar.

Seria interessante criar algum sinônimo em alguma delas? Mesclar algumas? Tomar outra ação?

O que mais tem a dizer sobre elas?

Agradeço a colaboração de todos.

Comment: Não vejo necessidade em uma tag especifica de uma classe do Java.

Comment: @renan pode ser mesmo, só não tenho certeza, você chegou analisar as perguntas ou está falando genericamente?

Comment: Falando genericamente, é uma classe como qualquer outra. Pelo menos eu não sei o que "inputstream" tem de tão importante que precise de uma tag. Na minha opinião só da pergunta estar associada a tah "java" já é suficiente. Tem que ver o que a comunidade acha, eu acho desnecessário.

Comment: Hum... Isso é um problema velho lá no SOen, e o Java 8 fez a coisa piorar bastante. Por lá existe também a tag `inputstream` (com 2.9k perguntas) e ainda uma bifurcação de stream chamada `java-stream` para a enxurrada de perguntas do Java 8. Além dessas existem tags mais específicas como `bufferedinputstream` e `fileinputstream` que considero desnecessárias.

Comment: Para vocês terem ideia do tamanho da confusão, segue o primeiro parágrafo da descrição da tag `stream` no SOen: *A stream is a series of data elements which can be accessed in a serial fashion. For Java 8’s new Stream API, use the `java-stream` tag instead.* Acho que boa parte das pessoas não terá problemas distinguindo perguntas de IO de perguntas da nova API do Java 8 se adotássemos a convenção [tag:java] [tag:stream], dito isso a diferença semântica existe.

Comment: @renan acho que estás errado, há muitos problemas com essa classe. A não ser que conseguisses arranjar melhor para colocar...

Comment: @bigown há alguma tag para leitura e escrita em outra linguagem?

Comment: @JorgeB. qual é o problema de explicar isso na pergunta?

Comment: Eu realmente não consigo entender a utilidade de tags como "inputstream". Talvez exista no SOEn porque não conseguiram matá-la no começo e agora já está mais difícil. Não consigo ver ninguém se inscrevendo nessa tag ou buscando por ela. Não consigo ver com bons olhos alguém virar medalhista nessa tag. Todos os casos de uso dela poderiam ser substituídos por algo como "entrada-de-dados" e, associado a Java, quem quer que considere uma boa ideia procurar perguntas desse tipo poderia encontrá-las.